# Data frame loop filter to keep all occurrences in one instance

Tags: r, regex, loops, filter

I am subsetting a dataframe in a loop to execute some calculations.
In the first iteration I want to preserve the whole dataframe.
I cannot do that with the code I wrote, and the whole dataframe disappears.

Toy example

```
data <- data.frame(letters=c("a","b","c"))
for (j in 1:3){
    cols <- c(".*","a","b")
    df <- data %>% filter(letters %in% cols[j])
    write.csv(df,paste("result_",j,".csv", sep = ""), row.names = F)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use regex you can use `grepl` instead of `%in%`

```
data <- data.frame(letters=c("a","b","c"))
cols <- paste0('^', c(".*","a","b"), '$')
for (j in 1:3){
    df <- data %>% filter(grepl(cols[j], letters))
    # write.csv(df,paste("result_",j,".csv", sep = ""), row.names = F)
    print(df)
}
```

Since you're already using one tidyverse package (dplyr), you may be interested in a tidyverse alternative to this loop, using `purrr::iwalk`

```
library(purrr)

iwalk(cols, ~{
  df <- data %>% filter(grepl(.x, letters))
  write.csv(df, paste("result_", .y, ".csv", sep = ""), row.names = F)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'ggplot2':
#>   method         from 
#>   [.quosures     rlang
#>   c.quosures     rlang
#>   print.quosures rlang
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'rvest':
#>   method            from
#>   read_xml.response xml2

data <- data.frame(letters=c("a","b","c"))

f <- c("^.","^a","^b")

map(f, ~filter(data, str_detect(letters, .x)))
#> [[1]]
#>   letters
#> 1       a
#> 2       b
#> 3       c
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   letters
#> 1       a
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   letters
#> 1       b
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>